# Share Page Post Using FB.ui feed dialog

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-winjs-sdk

Sorry I Try to search for this error and no result i try to use facebook feed dialog to share page post from my app here is my code

```
     function shareOnFacebook() {
FB.ui(
  {
    method        : 'feed',
    display       : 'popup',
    link : "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=176944625849315",
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {

      // HERE YOU CAN DO WHAT YOU NEED
      console.log('OK! User has published on Facebook.');

    } else {
      console.log('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```

}

I get error

API Error Code: 1

API Error Description: An unknown error occurred

Error Message: kError 1349117: Attachment Link Invalid: Link data invalid. Link data must have string 'href' and 'text' attributes

and When I try add Picture with facebook path then try to run agin i got blank popup

any help please ?

Comment: You can not share content on facebook.com using the feed dialog. Try using the Share button instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

Answer (score 0):

Posting CBroe's comment as it seems to be the answer...

> You can not share content on facebook.com using the feed dialog. Try
>   using the Share button instead:
>   developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button –  CBroe

(Please +1 the comment.)

Answer (score -1):

Your call is wrong. At the end of `link : "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=176944625849315",` there should be no comma. Here is the correct code:

```
function shareOnFacebook() {
    FB.ui(
      {
        method        : 'feed',
        display       : 'popup',
        link : "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=176944625849315"
      },
      function(response) {

      }
);
```